# Can a Turn and Bank Indicator be combined with a VSI?

Tags: flight-instruments, antonov-225

I have found a picture of a VSI on an AN-225 that seems to have a slip indicator with another indicator above the slip indicator. May I know if the scale and the slip indicator is a turn and bank indicator?

[image]

Comment: If the picture is not enough to show that it can be, what kind of proof are you looking for?

Comment: Just looking at it that's what it appears to be; VSI+skid ball+turn and bank.  That is probably a caging knob for the gyro at the bottom. If the VSI is instantaneous reading, it would be useable for pitch control in IMC, so the instrument is probably intended as an all-in-one backup to the attitude gyro.  I've never seen one before, so can't be sure.

Comment: Are we sure the white needle is VSI? In MIG21 there is a similar instrument where the white needle is AOA if I remember correctly.

Comment: Why is the vertical needle shaped the way it is, with a long tail, some of which is painted black to hide it?  Is it possible that it is essentially just a weighted "pendulum", not connected to any internal mechanism?  If so, it not be a turn rate indicator, but rather would essentially provide the same information as the ball, but without the damping of the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

From a regulatory standpoint there is no requirement in the US under 91.205 for a bank/rate of turn instrument to be combined with the skid/slip indication of the ball.  The ball could legally be combined with any instrument, as long as it is in easy sight of the pilot.